# Отключить функцию exec() в java 8

Tags: java, компилятор

Как я могу отключить Runtime.getRuntime().exec("msg * 1") функцию на стадии запуска jar файла(в аргументах запуска)?

Comment: зачем это надо?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Достаточно просто установить менеджер безопасности и программа не сможет выполнять никаких потенциально опасных действий без явного разрешения:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());

        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad.exe");
    }
}
```

Менеджер безопасности можно установить и без модификации кода программы, передав JVM при запуске ключ `-Djava.security.manager`.